# assertEquals does not properly evaluate test junit parameterized

Tags: android, kotlin, junit

I am creating a test to test If my class mapper works correctly. The mapper is correct but somehow assertEquals does not properly recognize that my actual and expected are equals it says its pointing to different object so its not equals

```
@RunWith(Parameterized::class)
class PaginationToPresentationMapperTest(
    private val given: PaginationDomainModel,
    private val expected: PaginationPresentationModel
) {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @Parameters(name = "Given {0} then {1}")
        fun data(): Collection<Array<*>> = listOf(
            testCase(
                nextCursor = null,
                prevCursor = null
            ),
            testCase(
                nextCursor = "next_id",
                prevCursor = null
            ),
            testCase(
                nextCursor = null,
                prevCursor = "prev_id"
            )
        )

        private fun testCase(
            nextCursor: String?,
            prevCursor: String?
        ) = arrayOf(
            PaginationDomainModel(
                nextCursor = nextCursor,
                prevCursor = prevCursor
            ),
            PaginationPresentationModel(
                nextCursor = nextCursor,
                prevCursor = prevCursor
            )
        )
    }

    private lateinit var classUnderTest: PaginationToPresentationMapper

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        classUnderTest = PaginationToPresentationMapper()
    }

    @Test
    fun `When toPresentation`() {
        // given

        // when
        val actual = classUnderTest.toPresentation(given)

        // then
        assertEquals(expected, actual)
    }
}
```

Fail:

```
expected:<link.limecode.newsfeed.presentation.model.pagination.PaginationPresentationModel@7bd7d6d6> but was:<link.limecode.newsfeed.presentation.model.pagination.PaginationPresentationModel@50029372>
Expected :link.limecode.newsfeed.presentation.model.pagination.PaginationPresentationModel@7bd7d6d6
Actual   :link.limecode.newsfeed.presentation.model.pagination.PaginationPresentationModel@50029372
```

Comment: From where you are passing  (expected: PaginationPresentationModel ) value???

I think, in you Mapper class you are creating new instance of  PaginationPresentationModel and in expected param, you are getting another new  instance of PaginationPresentationModel. So assertEqual is failing. Rather than asserting object, You can assert values inside the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `equals` method of your `PaginationPresentationModel`. By default, the `equals` method only compares instance equality, so two different objects with the same field values will not be equal.

If you use a `data class`, Kotlin will generate a value-based equals for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I forgot to use data class on PaginationPresentationModel. My bad since I am using data class on my models